# Problème with encoding git + powershell

Tags: git, powershell, encoding

I've got problem with powershell, encoding and git command.
In powershell console i do:

```
PS C:\Workspace\REPO1> $env:LC_ALL='C.UTF-8'
PS C:\Workspace\REPO1> git log --name-only --oneline --no-decorate --since="40 day ago"
4796b59 Merge branch 'develop'
cdbd6ec Modification gestion de la remise en impayé
webcom/automates/EDI/edi_bdx_a_reverser_alz_mrp.BSI
webcom/parametrage/webcom-profirst-dev-julien.xml
8f8995f simulation = FAUX
Automate/relances_impayes/bureau traitement impayes V2.bsi
d00f668 Merge branch 'Impayés' into develop
c9d49f3 MEP
Deploiement/20200320 - Relance impayés/Definitions catalogues/ZXREL.txt
Deploiement/20200320 - Relance impayés/Scripts/01_import_modeles_docs.bsi
Deploiement/20200320 - Relance impayés/Scripts/bureau traitement impayes V2.bsi
Deploiement/20200320 - Relance impayés/Scripts/fonctions_impayes.bsi
Deploiement/20200320 - Relance impayés/Scripts/import_TAB.bsi
Deploiement/20200320 - Relance impayés/Scripts/import_impayés_catalogue_REL_format_20200210.BSI
Deploiement/20200320 - Relance impayés/Scripts/librairies/fonctions_array.bsi
Deploiement/20200320 - Relance impayés/Scripts/librairies/fonctions_donnees.bsi
Deploiement/20200320 - Relance impayés/Scripts/librairies/fonctions_std.bsi
Deploiement/20200320 - Relance impayés/data/REL.csv
Deploiement/20200320 - Relance impayés/data/Relances Impayés.xlsm
Deploiement/20200320 - Relance impayés/data/TAB.csv
Deploiement/20200320 - Relance impayés/data/modeles de documents.csv
1bff5eb exclusion prélevés
Automate/BUREAU génération appel de prime.bsi
```

Accent are good display.
But if in a .ps1 fil i do the same think. accent are not correctly display.

```
$env:LC_ALL='C.UTF-8'
$gitHist = (git log --name-only --oneline --no-decorate --since="40 day ago")
Write-Host $gitHist
```

Output:

```
4796b59 Merge branch 'develop' cdbd6ec Modification gestion de la remise en impay├® webcom/automates/EDI/edi_bdx_a_reverser_alz_mrp.BSI webcom/parametrage/webcom-profirst-dev-julien.xml 8f8995f simulation = FAUX Automate/relances_impayes/bureau traitement impayes V2.bsi d00f668 Merge branch 'Impay├®s' into develop c9d49f3 MEP Deploiement/20200320 - Relance impay├®s/Definitions catalogues/ZXREL.txt Deploiement/20200320 - Relance impay├®s/Scripts/01_import_modeles_docs.bsi Deploiement/20200320 - Relance impay├®s/Scripts/bureau traitement impayes V2.bsi Deploiement/20200320 - Relance impay├®s/Scripts/fonctions_impayes.bsi Deploiement/20200320 - Relance impay├®s/Scripts/import_TAB.bsi Deploiement/20200320 - Relance impay├®s/Scripts/import_impay├®s_catalogue_REL_format_20200210.BSI Deploiement/20200320 - Relance impay├®s/Scripts/librairies/fonctions_array.bsi Deploiement/20200320 - Relance impay├®s/Scripts/librairies/fonctions_donnees.bsi Deploiement/20200320 - Relance impay├®s/Scripts/librairies/fonctions_std.bsi Deploiement/20200320 - Relance impay├®s/data/REL.csv Deploiement/20200320 - Relance impay├®s/data/Relances Impay├®s.xlsm Deploiement/20200320 - Relance impay├®s/data/TAB.csv Deploiement/20200320 - Relance impay├®s/data/modeles de documents.csv 1bff5eb exclusion pr├®lev├®s Automate/BUREAU g├®n├®ration appel de prime.bsi
```

And so i can't use the output to do Test-path for esemple are other command.

```
If ((Test-Path -LiteralPath $pathFile ) -eq $True)
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting the locale in your [profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7) setup script?

Comment: Yes, but style have the same problem

Comment: Try `[System.Console]::OutputEncoding=[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8` along with `$env:LC_ALL='C.UTF-8'` _before_ `$gitHist = (git log …`